# C# MVC Allow Update Of Re-edited field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form on a mvc view that contains Name, Username, email address, drop down list for branch and department. There are 2 stored procedures that is checking for duplicate Username and Email address. An error will be shown if the user clicks the update button.

**Scenario 1**

1. If the user deletes the username and enters a unique one the form will not submit because email address is still existent in the database.

How can I allow the update to continue if the user puts back the original Username

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(ApplicationUserModel model)
    {
        var appmodel = new ApplicationUserModel();
        appmodel.UserDetails = await ClaimsService.GetApplicationUserByID(model.Users.UserID);
        appmodel.Users = await ClaimsService.GetUserNameByID(model.Users.UserName);
        appmodel.User = await ClaimsService.GetEmailAddressIfExists(model.Users.EmailAddress);
        if (!appmodel.UserDetails.Name.Equals(model.Users.Name) || appmodel.UserDetails.BranchID != model.Users.BranchID || appmodel.UserDetails.DepartmentID != model.Users.DepartmentID )
        {
            if(!appmodel.UserDetails.UserName.Equals(model.Users.UserName) || !appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress.Equals(model.Users.EmailAddress))
            {
                model.UserNameErrorMessage = "Username already exists";
                model.EmailAddressErrorMessage = "Email address already exists";
                model.Username = appmodel.Users.UserName;
                model.EmailAddress = appmodel.User.EmailAddress;
                model.Users = new Model.Applications.Tables.tblUsers() { Archive_User = "0", StatusID = 1 };
                model.BranchSelectList = new SelectList(await BranchServices.GetBranchByCompanyID(1), "BranchID", "BranchFullName");
                model.DepartmentSelectList = new SelectList(await DepartmentService.GetAllActiveDepartments(1), "DepartmentID", "Department");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        await ClaimsService.UpdateUserAsync(model.Users);
        string redirectUrl = string.Format("/ApplicationUsers/Users");
        return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { type = Service.Utils.StringHelper.Types.UpdateSuccess, url = redirectUrl });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the old value (of username alone then email) with the new value if they are the same then don't check if it exists before. if they are different then check if the new is unique

If email was 'user1@example.com' , username = 'user1'

and the he entered email  = 'user1@eample.com' but username = 'user1updated'

You first check old email and new email (both are 'user1@example') then it is ok.
then check the old username with the new username (here are different) so I check the existence of new username ('user1updated') in the database if it not there I update otherwise don't update

Comment: please give an example

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(ApplicationUserModel model)
    {
        string redirectUrl;
        var appmodel = new ApplicationUserModel();
        appmodel.UserDetails = await ClaimsService.GetApplicationUserByID(model.Users.UserID);
        appmodel.Users = await ClaimsService.GetUserNameByID(model.Users.UserName);
        appmodel.User = await ClaimsService.GetEmailAddressIfExists(model.Users.EmailAddress);
        if(appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress == model.Users.EmailAddress || appmodel.UserDetails.UserName == model.Users.UserName)
        {
            if (!appmodel.UserDetails.Name.Equals(model.Users.Name) || appmodel.UserDetails.BranchID != model.Users.BranchID || appmodel.UserDetails.DepartmentID != model.Users.DepartmentID)
            {
                await ClaimsService.UpdateUserAsync(model.Users);
                redirectUrl = string.Format("/ApplicationUsers/Users");
                return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { type = Service.Utils.StringHelper.Types.UpdateSuccess, url = redirectUrl });
            }
            else if (appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress != model.Users.EmailAddress || appmodel.UserDetails.UserName != model.Users.UserName)
            {
                if (!appmodel.UserDetails.Name.Equals(model.Users.Name) || appmodel.UserDetails.BranchID != model.Users.BranchID || appmodel.UserDetails.DepartmentID != model.Users.DepartmentID)
                {
                    await ClaimsService.UpdateUserAsync(model.Users);
                    redirectUrl = string.Format("/ApplicationUsers/Users");
                    return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { type = Service.Utils.StringHelper.Types.UpdateSuccess, url = redirectUrl });
                }

                if(appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress == model.Users.EmailAddress)
                {
                    model.EmailAddressErrorMessage = "";
                }
                if(appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress != model.Users.EmailAddress)
                {
                    model.EmailAddressErrorMessage = "Email address already exists";
                }
                if(appmodel.UserDetails.UserName == model.Users.UserName)
                {
                    model.UserNameErrorMessage = "";
                }
                if (appmodel.UserDetails.UserName != model.Users.UserName)
                {
                    model.UserNameErrorMessage = "Username already exists";
                }
                model.Username = appmodel.Users.UserName;
                model.EmailAddress = appmodel.User.EmailAddress;
                model.Users = new Model.Applications.Tables.tblUsers() { Archive_User = "0", StatusID = 1 };
                model.BranchSelectList = new SelectList(await BranchServices.GetBranchByCompanyID(1), "BranchID", "BranchFullName");
                model.DepartmentSelectList = new SelectList(await DepartmentService.GetAllActiveDepartments(1), "DepartmentID", "Department");
                return View(model);
            }
            await ClaimsService.UpdateUserAsync(model.Users);
            redirectUrl = string.Format("/ApplicationUsers/Users");
            return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { type = Service.Utils.StringHelper.Types.UpdateSuccess, url = redirectUrl });
        }


        if (appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress == model.Users.EmailAddress)
        {
            model.EmailAddressErrorMessage = "";
        }
        if (appmodel.UserDetails.EmailAddress != model.Users.EmailAddress)
        {
            model.EmailAddressErrorMessage = "Email address already exists";
        }
        if (appmodel.UserDetails.UserName == model.Users.UserName)
        {
            model.UserNameErrorMessage = "";
        }
        if (appmodel.UserDetails.UserName != model.Users.UserName)
        {
            model.UserNameErrorMessage = "Username already exists";
        }
        model.Username = appmodel.Users.UserName;
        model.EmailAddress = appmodel.User.EmailAddress;
        model.Users = new Model.Applications.Tables.tblUsers() { Archive_User = "0", StatusID = 1 };
        model.BranchSelectList = new SelectList(await BranchServices.GetBranchByCompanyID(1), "BranchID", "BranchFullName");
        model.DepartmentSelectList = new SelectList(await DepartmentService.GetAllActiveDepartments(1), "DepartmentID", "Department");
        return View(model);

    }
```